# resin project, jdk8 has a high cpu load ,but jdk7 not

Tags: java, spring, jvm, java-8, resin

It is a project deployed in resin.the OS is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)

it uses spring 2.5.6 and struts2 , .. for some reason ,we need to deploy it in jdk8  ,it is too complex to upgrade the spring version  ,so we change one class in spring to make it support jdk8 ,It seems work well ,but after about half an hour , the cpu load rises to 10 ,sometimes higher than that . we have tried our best but havn't fount the reason . Is there goods suggestions to analyze the reason,or anyone meeting the similar problem ?

Comment: have you checked GC load? tried a java profiler?

Comment: Yes.  both Young  and full gc takes nearly the same time when the load is still normal(both default collector)  ,when load goes high ,gc takse longer time ,but I think this is caused  by  high load  rather than cause the high load